# Multiple Charset

Tags: php, ajax, utf-8, iso-8859-1

**The Scenario**:
I have an web app which has a custom register form integrated to Mailman. When the user submits the form, an Ajax function call a PHP script which stores the data in the database. The call back of this function submit to Mailman register form, which adds the user to a mail list.

**The Problem**: the Mailman register form is having a problem when I submit special characters, like: ç, é, í, ó, etc. All these characters are converted to strange characters. For example, if I submit "Módulo", the Mailman receives "MÃ©dulo".

How can I some this problem?

**Important**: the form of my web app uses UTF8. I think Mailman is using: ISO-8859-1. Can I convert the values of the fields only when the form is being submitted?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can, yes. Use [mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).